# how to use "setFieldHint" in CRUD form?

Tags: atk4, agiletoolkit

I want to add hint to the CRUD form but I receive error.

```
 $temp_crud->getElement('pin')->setFieldHint('the hint');
```

Answer (score 1):

simply add this to your Model:

```
$this->addField('my_field')->hint('this hint will show on the form');
```

Alternatively you can do

```
if($temp_crud->form) {
    $temp_crud->form->getElement('pin')->setFieldHint('the hint');
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work! Application Error: Method is not defined for this object

Exception_Logic, code: 0

Additional information:

    class: Field
    method: hint
    arguments:
        0: this hint will show on the form

Comment: you need to do this inside your Model class.

Comment: another note is that you should do crud->form->getElement, but you must be mindful that crud->form does only exist if you click on EDIT button.

Comment: Roman, I add the first code to the model! but it doesn't work altough the second one must work...